# storing password using shared preference in android

Tags: android, preferences

I am using shared preference to store password but when ever my application starts it again ask preference value .i want once i have entered the  preference password it should be fixed it should  ask me again and again.

Comment: please, show your code. It is difficult to say what's wrong without it.

Comment: Can you please post your code which stores password in SharedPreferences

Comment: Storing the password is one thing - retrieving and checking it on next start a different one :-)

Comment: please post the code to improve question i could 've have get used from it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where you want save your password use below code -

```
   Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("password", 0).edit();
   editor.putString("password", "your password");
   editor.commit();
```

And where you like to get it back put below code there -

```
   SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("password", 1);
   String password = pref.getString("password", "");
```

If still its not working, Put your code out here.